# What happens when a map has to be resized to accommodate more items?

Tags: java

What happens when a map has to be resized to accommodate more items? What will happen if another thread calls get() when resizing is underway?

Comment: Stuff will happen.  Stuff is entirely dependent on the map implementation.  For instance MyPersonalMapWhichCrashesOnAnything will throw a UnsupportedOperationException if you so much as look at it, whereas HashMap is more resilient.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the map. Are you referring to an array based implementation?

Comment: @Taylor have you published your class as a library? I would be interested in using it.

Comment: @Taylor: HashMap is not more resilient. It's not thread-safe, and anything could thus happen.

Comment: @Macs: Things will break, unless you're using a `ConcurrentMap` that handles those cases properly.

Comment: @JBNizet HashMap is not more resilient than MyPersonalMapWhichCrashesOnAnything ?  Did you hear a whooshing sound? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is one word it will got crashed and will throw Exception might be UnsupportedOperationException.the reason behind this is ..

As HashMap is not thread safe so when another thread will try to read the data, it will not allow and stuff will occurs which completely depend upon implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Your question on what will happen if another thread calls get() while the map is being resized reveals a general lack of intuition about the Java Memory Model. Specifically, if the map implementation you use is not thread-safe, it will be irrelevant when get() is called—in the middle of resizing or while the map is sitting completely idle: the call from another thread will *always* be broken due to write visibility issues.

Simply put, there are only two conditions in Java: thread-safe and not thread-safe. No further details are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain what will happen there. Just in case - **one should not do this**.

As far as I understand `HashMap` implementation, if you are writing to it with a single thread, it would not crash, but might not find your item. For two concurrent threads it would crash very early because of `ConcurrentModificationException`.

**Why it won't crash**

- Resize operation in `HashMap` is sort of atomic - it first allocates your table and re-indexes items into it and then replaces an existing table with a new one
- Table size grows, but does not shrink, so even with broken indexing function you are still within bounds.
- `get` will never throw a null pointer exception - one can check that `getEntry(Object key)` would never throw a `NullPointerException`.

**Why it might not find your item**

Because `table[hash(key)]` operation is non-atomic. You might run into a situation when you have a hash value for an old map, but after resize it's already a new one.